# TextMate very slow on Samba Drive

Tags: samba, text-editors, sftp, textmate

I loaded an entire Samba drive as a TextMate project.

Every single time I lose cursor of TextMate to do something else like checking the web browser... and then try to click on TextMate again it gives me a spinning beach ball for 3 seconds.

I was wondering if there was a setting that would make it faster to focus the cursor in TextMate without the 3 second wait each time.

Also of note, if I open the files one at a time and not as an entire project, I don't get this problem, so I assume it has something to do with the number of files loaded in a TextMate project.

Comment: Is this share on your network? It may simply be a latency thing. When you connect to it in the Finder, do you get the same 3 second delay? Can you try another connection method like [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html)?

Comment: You might also have `Save files when focus is lost` enabled in TextMate's preferences (under Advanced > Saving) which may involve a lot of work as it's trying to figure out what to save. Every time you go back to TextMate, it will also check to see if any of the files on disk have changes since the last window refresh, since it will try to load these seamlessly for you.

Comment: Well the network is very fast, I think it's just the sheer amount of files that TextMate checks.  Save files when focus is lost is disabled, that was the first thing I thought of.  I think TextMate tries to check the files for consistency each time on focus regardless... unfortunately I can't find where to disable that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a great little plugin that might help called **ReMate**. It stops TextMate from automatically checking all the files in the project for changes when TextMate gains focus again. I use it for working with remote drives mounted with FUSE as that had the some problem.

You can download it on Github
https://github.com/ciaran/Remate

The plugin adds an new item in the window menu called "*Disable Refresh on Regaining Focus*", if you check it then things get nice and speedy.

While it is active if you want to manually refresh the files right click in the sidebar and choose "*Refresh All Projects*"